# Determine which of two possible result objects has been returned

Tags: kotlin, integration-testing, android-livedata

I have a `Result<SuccessData, ErrorType>` sealed class that I use to represent a response from an api. In fragments, I use this to parse the response:

```
activity?.onResult(response?.result, onSuccess = {
    // Act on successful response
}, onValidationError = {
    // Act on errored response
})
```

Now, in my tests, I would like to test the response and run asserts on if it's a successful response, or an error response (and what type of response).

If I have a variable like `response: Result<SuccessData, ErrorType> = someResponse` returned, is it possible for me to do something like

```
// Test Successful Response
Assert.assertTrue(response.result.value is SuccessData)

// Test Failed Response
Assert.assertTrue(response.result.value is ErrorType)
```

EDIT: Add Result Class

```
sealed class Result<out Success, out ErrorType> {
    companion object {
        fun <T> success(value: T): Ok<T> = Ok(value)
        fun <E> error(errors: List<E>): Error<E> = Error(errors)
    }

    // success response data
    data class Ok<out T> internal constructor(val data: T) : Result<T, Nothing>()

    // expected validation errors
    data class Error<out E> internal constructor(val errors: List<E>) : Result<Nothing, E>()

    sealed class GenericError {
        class Unknown : GenericError()
        class ServerDown : GenericError()
    }
}
```

Comment: How about testing it, telling what you expect to happen and what happens instead, and of course posting your code if you need clarifications?

Comment: @JBNizet I've have tried... `response.result.value` is not an actual thing, only `response.result` is legitimate. For example, `response` is a custom response object, and the `result` variable is `Result<SuccessData, ErrorType>`. I need to evaluate is result is SuccessData, or ErrorType, not sure how to do it (if possible).

Comment: Well, read the documentation, or the source code, or both, of the Result class. You haven't posted it, so how could we know?

Comment: @JBNizet behmm, well you could read my question clearly before commenting and being rude... I told you that the Result class is declared with type `Result<SuccessData, ErrorType>`. This means that a return value could be either `SuccessData` or `ErrorType`. But how can I unwrap the `Result<SuccessData, ErrorType>` to evaluate if it's `SuccessData` or `ErrorType`?. 

I've edited my question to contain the `Result<SuccessData, ErrorType>` class just for you

Comment: where have I been rude exactly? You realize that you have the source code, and yet you're unable to tell by yourself if using `response.result.value` is the right way to access the result. And yet you're asking us to tell you how to do it, but without providing the source code, despite being asked to do that twice. I have tried my best not being rude, but really, you're not making it easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to assert whether a response is successful or not.

```
// Test Successful Response
Assert.assertTrue(response.result is Result.Ok)

// Test Failed Response
Assert.assertTrue(response.result is Result.Error)
```

If you want to perform assertions on the data from the response, then you can write it like this.

```
if (response.result is Result.Ok) {
    Assert.assertEquals(result.data, "some data")
} else {
    fail()
}
```